# How to remove Document Inspector warning in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm running VBA scripts on a series of files that are XLSM type. While I'm trying to automate my processes, I'm getting stopped by this warning about the Document Inspector, meaning I have to click OK for every file.

Is there a script I can run on my files in advance, or embed one in my code, that will remove this warning?

---

### Warning Message

[image: Document Inspector error]

> Be careful! Parts of your document may include personal information
>   that can't be removed by the Document Inspector.

Answer (score 25):

Potential solutions to the "**Be careful! Parts of your document may include personal information
that can't be removed by the Document Inspector.**" warning message.

To remove **Document Inspector** warning in **Excel 2016** or **Excel 2013** you can check two things

> - Go to **File** in the upper left hand corner,
> - then **Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Privacy Options**
> - then ***un-check*** the check box that says "**Remove personal information from file properties on save**",
> - then hit **OK**.
>
> [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255584/be-careful-parts-of-your-document-may-include-personal-information-that-cannot-b)

Or

> - Go to **File > Info**
> - and click in "**Allow this information to be saved in your file**".
>
> The next time you save there should be no more warning.
>
> [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255584/be-careful-parts-of-your-document-may-include-personal-information-that-cannot-b)

Comment: Hi, that's great for one file but I've got 82 of them and would like to avoid opening each one. I tried recording your solution as a macro but it failed. Is there a VB solution?

Comment: @TessinOz Is it a mixture of Excel 2016 and 2013 or only 2016 and are you in a domain environment with Group Policies?

Answer (score 3):

### My Solution

Instead of disabling the **Document Inspector** which seems difficult to do in VB, I'm just blocking the message itself. I don't really care about the source file, I just want to seamlessly copy data out of them so this will work in my case just fine.

By adding this code to the start of my code, I no longer get the **Document Inspector** warning:

```
'Disable privacy settings warning
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: This does not work in every case.

Comment: @Tess - You should accept this answer here you wrote by turning the check mark green since it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

open the document > alt+f11 > Module Thisworbook input this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
End Sub
```